# That sounds like 'that do a full three men '. What is this guy exactly saying after the streamer said something to him?

Tags: grammar, spoken-english

I was watching videos on twitch. After one guy say something to one, I heard the guy saying that which sound like  "what do you mean one guy that do a full three men". I understand what they were talking about, but that sentence is weird to me that I thought that was grammatically wrong. I mean one part of the sentence, like "that do a " doesn't make sense.

The Twitch clip URL here: https://clips.twitch.tv/CorrectArborealPorcupinePhilosoraptor-sY9knYePzMZXR3lR

Comment: It's not clear from the clip what they are actually doing! The first speaker says "I don't know how you are in a position to [something] one guy." The second seems to imply that he has to do [whatever it is] to not one, but three men.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The streamer seems surprised by how the player they're addressing was able to die to one guy only.

I think this is what is said:

> "How do you even like... I don't know how you even put yourself in a position to die with the one guy."
>
> "What do you mean "one guy"? **I died to a full three men!**"

It becomes somewhat clearer when you listen to the consequential stream.
Here's a transcription:

> "Erm, I, erm, it seemed like it's - the one person was shooting at you."
>
> "No: one guy killed me, but it's a full three men holding us out."
>
> "Yeah, but, that - that's what I'm saying: how are you even - how do you, like, what .. whatever .."
>
> "By the second he was shooting me I'm dead."
>
> "You're at full health and you let one guy one-mag you."

(The OP might know this, but 'to one-mag someone' is to empty your entire weapon's magazine on someone in one go, which in many MMOs is a sure kill.)

Comment: Wow, I got the answer! Thank you for your explanation and advise that are so valuable and the transcription is so helpful to me. I did"t know this phrase "died to noun" which sounded like "that do" to my ears. But I hear that now.

Comment: "one guy one-mag you ' makes sense to me, but I didn't know it as a verb

Comment: I listened to the recording a couple more times and although I am still not sure I think your version (I died to a full three men) and not mine (That's your full three men) is the correct one. As a side note, I went for "your" as I was thinking of its use to refer to a typical or particular type of thing. (Your typical rap group, etc.)

Comment: Although I thought he said "died to a full three men" without "I , I am not sure whether it is now. Do you mean that "your" is also used except for explaining things that belongs or relates to someone ?

Comment: @Joachim Sorry, I thought i send it to PPH. He or she was thinking about the use of "yours"  that is a part of "that's your full three men" as he said.

Comment: @Joachim I was thinking so too. I agree with your opinion. But my English skill is not good, that's why i was not sure.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>They are playing a videogame against each other and chatting/bantering at the same time:</strike>

It is now clarified by OP that the two players are on the same team.

> How do you even like... I don't know how you even put yourself in a position to die with the one guy.
>
> What do you mean one guy? That's your full three men!

EDIT:

"That's your full three men!" is what I though I heard, with the determiner "your" referring to a typical or particular type of thing. [(See meaning 3 here.)](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/your)

**However, after reading @Joachim's version (I died to a full three men), I think his makes more sense and is more likely to be correct.**

Comment: To my ears, the word you give as **die** begins with an **s**. As in "**side** with one guy" but not even that.

Comment: Thank for all answers and comments! But I had lack of explanation about their situation. The first speaker is playing with the second one against other three guys. That's why i wonder the second really said "that's your full three men"

Comment: @ShotaTakagi ... Is a three-man group typical/common in this sort of video game?

Comment: Yes, it is. Exactly you are right.

Comment: In that case, there is some justification for my version (That's your full three men = That's the typical three men) but @Joachim's version (I died to a full three men) makes more sense and I think is more likely to be correct.

Comment: @PPH I am so thankful for your kindness. I didn't know the use of "your" which is so useful to me. I appreciate it.